# Show that $\mathbb CG$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb CH$

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group generated by $x,y$ with relation $xyx=yxy$.

Let $H$ be a group generated by $a,b$ with relation $a^2=b^3$.

Show that the group algebra $\mathbb CG$ given by the presentation for $G$ is isomorphic to the group algebra $\mathbb CH$ where $H$ is the group with presentation.

Can someone tell me what the question asking and how should I start it? I get really confusing with "given by the presentation" and "with presentation". How I see $\mathbb CG$ and $\mathbb CH$ is that they are group $\mathbb C$-span by element in the group, that is $\mathbb CG=\{a_0+a_1g_1+ ... +a_ng_n \mid a_i\in \mathbb C,~ g_i \in G\}$